# How can I let users choose an OpenCL device?

Tags: c, opencl

I'm writing a python/C application that uses OpenCL and I'd like to let the user choose his/her favorite OpenCL device to run it on.
This should happen offline, with the preferred device stored in an ini file.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this? The device ids aren't consistent between process calls, so I could store the device names and then perform string matching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The examples I've seen query the available platforms/devices (clGetAvailablePlatforms/Devices) and put the names in a combo box, then use the "selected index" of the combo box as indication of which device the user wants to use at runtime. 
So I'd say let the user select the index of the device as it shows up in clGetAvailablePlatforms/Device. The only problem with this is that if the user is constantly chaginging graphics cards or driver versions, the order can change. Then you need to get the precise device name string (which can also change between driver version - although vendors usually don't do that).

Comment: This works fairly well. The downside is that dual-device GPUs (or dual GPU systems like the Mac Pro late 2013) will have the same name for both. In that case, you get one, but you can't really reliably specify _which_ one.

Comment: Wish there was a solution without string matching though. Bit strange that they didn't address this in the spec.